# Isometries between two convex bodies

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, convexity

Let $A,B$ be two convex compact subsets with non-empty interior in a Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a bijective isometry between them.

> Does there exist an isometry $F\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that its restriction to $A$ is equal to $f$?

Remark. Necessarily $F$ is a composition of translation and orthogonal transformation.

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: convexity is not needed: non-empty interior is enough, moreover, having $n+1$ linearly independent points is enough. distances to these points determine the point in a space uniquely, so knowing images of these points you determine the images of every point of space.

Comment: @LevSoukhanov: Thanks, you are right.  This is a final answer in fact.

Comment: Even without $n+1$ linearly independent points, there exists an isometry such that its restriction is $f$; but in that case it is not unique.